# Opening firewall port to firebird service

Tags: port, firebird

I try to build mobile application which use firebird database. I need to open port 3050 for that service.

I have add rule to ZTE router both incoming and outgoing for port 3050 and also to bitdefender firewall. I have forward rule to specific ip, where firebird listen 3050 port.

When I use open port checker, it shows that 3050 port is open. But when I try to connect to firebird service with FlameRobin using my ip-adress, error message: unable to complete network request to host "86.115.60.xx"

WinShark [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3eZ3.jpg) shows something but I can't understand all information.

Comment: Opening the port in your router is not enough, you also have to define a port forwarding rule to the right host, and in addition you need to make sure that Firebird is listening on the right IP address(es) of the host.

Comment: However, you shouldn't access a Firebird server directly from a mobile application. Instead write a webservice to mediate between the application and the database. That will reduce the attack surface, and likely improve performance because Firebird's wire protocol is pretty chatty which doesn't perform well over higher latency networks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Check, what I added to text. I'll write (my first) webservice. Is it so that then webservice port (datasnap 211) should be open, not firebird port?

Comment: Also, if you use Firebird Events (notifications from server to clients) you would have to forward one more connections on yet one more port

Comment: Try tools like WireShark to research on which stage of many computer-to-computer-to-computer hops the connection attempt fails. For starters, it can be that Firebird does not receive incoming signal, or it can be that your client does not receive Firebird's answer. For the client it looks the same. But it would be different problems. Would you have Linux not Windows (or pre-SP2 XP Windows)  on the client you could use LFT for tracing 3050 port

Comment: @Arioch'The Look what WinShark information gave...

Comment: 1) it is always better to copy text than pictures. 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment

Comment: What I see - and I am not specialist in TCP - is that "open connection" packet is received - the "[SYN]" one, and the server starts the opening sequence. But then server confirms the receipt of the request - "[ACKnowledge]" flag and DENIES it - "[Reset]" flag. Maybe it is issue with firewall or antivirus on 1.2 machine. See also https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/1652/what-would-cause-rstack and https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2012